# rmarkdown - specifying output theme in site.yml removes navbar

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to set the output theme is one place instead of putting it in the yaml header of each individual rmarkdown file. So I have tried:

```
name: "casualties"
output_dir: "injuries"


navbar:
  left:
    - text: "Casualties"
      href: index.html
    - text: "Casualty map"
      href: casualtymap.html
    - text: "Frequently asked questions"
      href: faqs.html

output: 
    prettydoc::html_pretty:
          theme: cayman
          highlight: github
```

and then each individual page just has

```
---
title: "page title"
---
```

but the navigation bar does not appear. If I remove the output info then it does. Is there a way to do this that works please?

Edit:
following Anthon's comments I took the indentations from the examples in the [bookdown guide](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/rmarkdown-site.html#common-elements) and have found:

Using prettydoc the navbar is not rendered:

```
name: "Casualties"

navbar:
  left:
    - text: "Casualties"
      href: index.html
    - text: "Casualty map"
      href: casualtymap.html
    - text: "Frequently asked questions"
      href: faqs.html

output_dir: "injuries"

output: 
  prettydoc::html_pretty:
    theme: cayman
    highlight: github
```

but if I don't use prettydoc the navbar is rendered:

```
name: "Casualties"

navbar:
  left:
    - text: "Casualties"
      href: index.html
    - text: "Casualty map"
      href: casualtymap.html
    - text: "Frequently asked questions"
      href: faqs.html

output_dir: "injuries"

output:
  html_document:
    theme: cosmo
    highlight: textmate
```

Comment: Your first code chunk, the `theme:` and `highlight:` needs to be reindented properly due to YAML formatting. I tried to edit, but White spaces aren't considered characters, but it's crucial for YAML